# How we make a POST request and pass in the body a content?

Tags: azure-functions-core-tools

I have created a simple custom web page using HTML and JavaScript, that allows a user to select multiple languages of their choice to transalate text.

For example, lets say the user chooses English and Spanish and clicks on "Submit". I want to take the user selection, process it.

Comment: `method: 'POST',` will ensure it is a post logic

Comment: @brk is my JavaScript logic correct? How can it  pass in the body a content which is: { "lang": "yourSelectedLanguageCode" } ?

Answer (score 1):

Hi can you add this line "mode : 'cors'" in your code. See the below code

method : 'POST',
**mode : 'cors'**,
headers : {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
},

Comment: Hello, I am not sure I understand what you are saying? I believe you are getting an error because, I didn't share my HTTP POST URL due to privacy reasons.

Comment: My question was to see if my  Logic is correct for the JavaScript?

Comment: You can check on your side in console. If the same error is coming to you than you need to implement the above thing

Comment: Your code looks correct to me when i changed to some different POST URL it was working fine.

Comment: Hello Mahendra, my question is  how do we make a POST to the logic app URL and pass in the body a content which is: { "lang": "yourSelectedLanguageCode" } ? Is my JavaScript currently doing this you think?

Comment: For example, say the user selects English and French and click "submi". Will my Logic app schema, read this data properly based on the JavaScrip code?

Comment: Yes your code is correct issue is in API. Check this fiddle i have just changed the API in this everything is same: https://jsfiddle.net/h1n90cz7/

Comment: But Mahendra, right now my coding is just logging the result right? For example say I select Spanish( es-ES)in my web page and click submit. Will my Azure logic app JSON schema  able to read the user input and process it, with this code?

Comment: 1. No it is logging result after success of the Request. 2. You can try hitting actual API if no error is thrown and json response comes in console.log('got result:', result)) then your code is fine